# Is there a way to solve for $\sigma^2$ in linear regression only using least squares estimation?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear

If we only use least squares estimation, is there a way to solve for the variance of the conditional distribution of Y | X?  Or do we have to use Maximum Likelihood Estimation?

Additionally, do most software use MLE to solve for the paramters?